# What are swappable models in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello I am new to django. I have came across the term `Swappable` model, while reading about django models. I am not able to find the significance of `Swappable` model.

[image]

I have also inspected Model._meta object. It contains a member attribute `swappable`, which is None by default.

I have tried to search documentation. I have also googled out, but couldn't find any reference to swappable model.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The term `Swappable` refers to the `UserModel` of django [[1]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/), which can be swapped inside of a project into a custom implementation and as long as you provide the proper API it works with other apps that rely on this API.

The documentation regarding migrations needs to take care of this topic, as it is related to ORM.

`Swappable` [is considered to be private API](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19103), but there is also [wq/django-swappable-models](https://github.com/wq/django-swappable-models) which makes this concept reusable for you in your app.